# Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ that verifies for all $x_1,x_2$: $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| \leq 5|cos(x_1)-cos(x_2)|$ so $f(x)$ is periodic

Tags: calculus, functions, solution-verification, periodic-functions

**Question:**
Prove: Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ that verifies for all $x_1,x_2$: $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| \leq 5|cos(x_1)-cos(x_2)|$ so $f(x)$ is periodic.

**My answer:**

*Corrected answer with the help of Martin R*

By absurd let suppose that $f(x)$ is not a periodic function. So by the negation of the definition of a periodic function we get: $∃x_0∈R s.t. ∀T∈R⇒f(x_0)≠f(x_0+T)$

If it is true for all T it is in particular true when for T=2π and in this case we get::

on one side $|f(x_0)−f(x_0+2π)|>0$ as $f(x_0)≠f(x_0+2π)$ by the asbsurd assumption.
on the other side : $|cos(x_0)−cos(x_0+2π)|=0$
Contradiction as |f(x_0)−f(x_0+2π)| can not be at the same time STRICTLY positive and STRICTLY EQUAL to zero.
Q.E.D.

---

*False first answer*

By absurd let suppose that $f(x)$ is not a periodic function. That means $\forall x' \in \mathbb{R}$ it exists only a finite number of points (sequence) $(x'_n)_{1\leq n \leq N}$ s.t. $f(x')=f(x'_n)=y'$ and that $f(x)$ is not necessarly bounded.

If it is true for all $x$ it is in particular true for the following two sequences $(x_{1n}=2 \pi n)_{1\leq n \leq N} \Rightarrow f(x_{1n})=y_1 \; \forall 1\leq n \leq N$
$(x_{2n}=2 \pi n)_{N_{2i}\leq n \leq N_{2f}} \Rightarrow f(x_{2n})=y_2 \; \forall N_{2i}\leq n \leq N_{2f} $.
Make attention to the fact that by assumption $y_1 \neq y_2$. In other words $f(x)$ equal to $y_1$ on only a finish set of points which are all differents from the finish set of points where $f(x)=y_2 \neq y_1$, and this set is too finih.

Now it came that on one side: $|f(x_{1n})-f(x_{2n})|=|y_1-y_2|>0$ as $y_1 \neq y_2$.
And on the other side we get: $|cos(x_{1n})-cos(x_{2n})|=|1-1|=0$
Contradiction as in this case we get: $0<|f(x_{1n})-f(x_{2n})|=|y_1-y_2| \leq 5|cos(x_{1n})-cos(x_{2n})|=0$ Hence in he same time  $|f(x_{1n})-f(x_{2n})|$ is STRICLY greater than zero AND equal to zero and that impossible.
Q.E.D.

Is this correct? I am sincerelly completely stuck on this (good) question and i don' see any other way to prove it. I will be happy to read differents answers.

Thank you

---

Comment: When you assume $f$ is not periodic, then the right assumption is that there exist at least one such $x'$, not for all $x'.$ Besides, I don't think that's the right assumption to have only finite number of points that retake any given value. You could have infinitely many such points, but just not periodic.

Comment: What is the definition of periodic ? 
$$\exists a: \forall x\in D\implies f(x+a) = f(x).$$
So to assume the contrary, you will have:
$$\forall a: \exists x\in D\implies f(x+a)\neq f(x).$$

Comment: Yes with the help of @Martin R i ve edited my first prove by absurd. If you can tell me now if it is correct i will be very happy about it. Thk

Comment: @X0-user-0X: Please do not change your question significantly after receiving answers. This invalidates the given answers and confuses future readers of this Q&A. If you have a new proof that you want to be checked then please ask a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said

> By absurd let suppose that $f(x)$ is not a periodic function. That means $\forall x' \in \mathbb{R}$ it exists only a finite number of points (sequence) $(x'_n)_{1\leq n \leq N}$ s.t. $f(x')=f(x'_n)=y'$.

but that is not a valid conclusion. For example $f(x) = x \sin(x)$ is not periodic, but all values are taken infinitely often.

A simple direct proof would be: For all $x \in \Bbb R$ is
$$
 |f(x+2 \pi)- f(x)| \le 5 |\cos(x + 2 \pi) - \cos(x)| = 0 \\
\implies f(x+2 \pi) = f(x) \, ,
$$
which shows that $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: thk for your answer can you correct my proof?

Comment: @X0-user-0X: No, I can't. As I explained, your first sentence is already wrong. That can  not easily be “corrected.”

Comment: If I had "and that $f(x)$ is not necessarly bounded" in my assumption is it correct now?

Comment: @X0-user-0X: No. $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$ is  bounded and not periodic, but all values in the range $[-1, 1]$ are taken infinitely often. – A proof by contradiction is simply the wrong tool here.

Comment: Thk for your usefull comment. I ve tried to prove by absurd in a different way which is finally very very very close to your solution. I don't want to waste your time but if you can look at it and tell me that everything is ok i will be very happy about it. (it should be very quick) Thk again.

Comment: @X0-user-0X Using a proof by contradiction here is ugly, even if you can make it work.